# I am using beautifulsoup in python 3. But "html.parser" not give me the all code of website

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My code is

```
import urllib
import urllib.request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
fed = "https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track&tracknumbers=870915037012296&cntry_code=us&wsch=true"

show = urllib.request.urlopen(fed)
soup = BeautifulSoup(show,"html.parser")

print(soup)
```

I am trying to fetch the delivery address from fedex and status.But this code not fetching all the data of my URL

Comment: Which code do you expect and what exactly is missing?

Comment: I expect the code having delivering address, status , shipping date and delivering date

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use [Fedex SOAP API](http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/) directly. There is a Python wrapper - [`python-fedex`](http://python-fedex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html).

Example how to track a package can be found [here](http://python-fedex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html#track-a-package).

Comment: I am not understanding working of fedex.py. Can you please give me example of tracking a number and please also tell me which libraries need to install to track fedex package